# Counterexample pointwise completebess

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Theorem : X topological, Y metric, A subspace of $Y^X$

A closed in $Y^X$ with the producttopology and $cl(pr_x(A))$ complete in Y, then A is pointwise complete (i.e. every pointwise cauchyfilter converges).

(A pointwise cauchyfilter is a filter such that every projection is a cauchyfilter in Y)

The opposite of this theorem is false, but i can't find a counterexample.

Comment: If you put the Tychonoff topology on $Y^X$, what does it matter that $X$ is topological? It might as well be a cardinal number.

Comment: So to be clear, you're asking for a metric space $Y$, a closed subspace $A$ of $Y^X$, such that closures of projections of $A$ are complete with the induced metric, but $A$ itself is not?

Comment: No i'm looking for a subspace of $Y^X$ that is pointwise closed and an x in X such that cl(pr_x(A)) is not complete

Answer (score 0):

Is this a good counterexample?

Y = (0,inf)
X={0,1}
$f_n(0)$ =1/n
$f_n(1)$ =n

A={$f_n$}

A has no pointwise cauchyfilters, so they all converge. A is pointwise complete. $cl(pr_0(A)) = cl(1/n) intersection (0,inf)$ is not complete.